# C end of line char

Tags: c, char, newline

I'm having this problem.

```
char buffer[100];
buffer[0] = "\n";
```

For some reason, the following statement is true

```
buffer[0] == 'T'
```

When it should be the "\n" ascii. Why?

Comment: You are comparing `char*` to a `char`.

Comment: `buffer[0] = "\n"` is not a compilable code. You code will not compile and, obviously, will not run. Yet, you claim that you have `buffer[0] == 'T'` (implying that you ran the code). This means that the code above is fake and has no relation to the question. Please, post real code. At this time the question makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @AndreyT it will compile and run. That's how C's typing works. It gives a warning during compiling, though: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to '`char`' from '`char [2]`'. That's why I always compile with `-Wall -Werror` :)

Comment: @AndreyT: A good compiler will warn you about that line of code, but it's not actually illegal. You almost never want to assign a `char*` to a `char` but C will happily let you shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @WTP: This is *not* how C's typing works. This is how the OPs *compiler* works. C language does not allow one to convert pointers to integers without a cast. In C the above is *constraint violation*, i.e. what we typically call an *error*. If the OPs compiler issues warnings for full-blown constraint violations, then OP has to carefully watch these warnings, I guess. (Or find a better compiler?)

Comment: @Code Monkey: Frankly, I don't see a single place in the above code where anyone would be "comparing `char*` to a `char`". Yet the comment has 5 upvotes. Maybe I need new glasses...

Comment: @Andrey: Sadly, it does compile with gcc-4.3.4 - see here : http://ideone.com/1wlte

Comment: @Andrey: "\n" is char* not a char.

Comment: @Clueless: Yes, it is explicitly illegal in C language. I'll say it agaun: ANSI C language does not allow one to convert pointer to integers (or vice versa) without an explicit cast.

Comment: @AndreyT: From the C99 specification: "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type."

Comment: @Code Monkey: When the compiler issues a diagnostic message (a warning in this case), the code is considered invalid. With certain compilers extra reserahc is needed to determine whether the diagnostic message constitutes a genuinte constaint violation. In this case it does. So, again, the code is not valid C code.

Comment: @Clueless: The quote you priovided refers to *explicit conversion*. What it says is that you can do `int i = (int) ptr` with an explicit cast. The section of the standard you quoted does not apply to implicit conversions.

Comment: @AndreyT: Warnings != Will Not Compile. You said: "buffer[0] = "\n" is not a compilable code. Your code will not compile." This statement is wrong as I have proven. You are correct it is not proper code.

Comment: @Clueless: If you want top test the actual validity of the code, use Comeau Online compiler in C mode (http://comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/). That compiler is very pedantic and is recognized as the best tool for this kind of verifications.

Comment: @Code Monkey: Incorrect. I said that the code will not compile as C code, becuase it is invalid. I never said that one cannot dig out some semi-broken loosely-C-related (and misconfigured) compiler somewhere which will accept the code. As the first line of testing, if the code is not compiled by Comeau Online, the code is not compilable. Period.

Comment: That is from section 6.3.2.3. The first line of subsection 6.3 is as follows: "Several operators convert operand values from one type to another automatically. This
subclause specifies the result required from such an implicit conversion, as well as those
that result from a cast operation (an explicit conversion)." So it applies to both.

Comment: @Clueless: You are confused. What 6.3 says is that **if** the automatic conversion is allowed, then it behaves as described in 6.3.2.3. **If it is allowed**, again. Now, in order to find out whether it is allowed, you have to go to the description of the specific operator. In this case it is assignment. Assignment like this is **not allowed**. See 6.5.16.1. There's no pointer-to-integer assignment in C. Moreover, to save you saome trouble, no context in C allows automatic pointer-to-integer conversion. Pointer-to-integer conversion in ANSI C always requires an explicit cast.

Comment: @Andrey: Look - I am sure there are pedantic compilers out there. But you didn't say that at first. Just admit that you made a mistake in your statement and should have said your second comment in this thread first because the first one is not correct. The bottom line is it does compile albeit with warnings.

Comment: @Code Monkey: That would apply if the OP explcicitly states that the question is about GCC in "loose" mode. The proper way to use GCC is to compile with `-pedantic-errors` at all times. Withouit `-pedantic-errors` that compiler is a joke. Try it in this case.

Comment: @Code Monkey: I still don't see a `char*` to `char` comparison in the code.

Comment: From that section, "In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the
assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left
operand." This is done by the arithmetic conversions as specified in section 6.3, including the implementation-defined behavior as I referenced above. Constraint violations are limited to the discarding of qualifiers from pointer-to-pointer assignments, which can severely break otherwise valid assumptions made by code elsewhere. In any case, this discussion is dull, so I will stop contributing.

Comment: @Clueless: I don't know why you skipped to that place right away. Right above that C language standard lists **Constraints**: all possible cases of valid assignment in 6.5.16.1/1. That is an *exhaustive* list. No other assignments are allowed. There's no pointer-to-integer assignment there (and integer-to-pointer is limited to constant zero on RHS). That's it. This is C99, BTW, but it was exactly like that in C89/90 as well. The last C that allowed you to pull of tricks like that was either K&R (not sure it was legal there) or even CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `*buffer[0] = '\n'`. I think that would give you the desired result, as it is `char` you are assigning not `string`. For `string` use double quotes and for `char` single quote.

As rightly pointed in the comment `buffer[0]` is char pointer, so first it needs to be allocated memory too. `calloc` would be a better choice here as it is going to assign default 0 values whereas `malloc` will just allocate space having garbage values.

Comment: You were right the first time. `buffer` is a stack allocated array with 100 `char`s in it, and `buffer[0]` is the first element. The correct statement is `buffer[0] = '\n';`.

Comment: @Nik: "As rightly pointed in the comment buffer[0] is char pointer, so first it needs to be allocated memory too." What exactly is meant by this statament? `buffer[0]` is not a char pointer, it is just a `char`. How can anyone "allocate" anything for `buffer[0]` here with `calloc` is totally unclear to me.

Comment: @Nik: The comment by @Amigable Clark Kant is very poorly worded. `buffer[0]` is a `char`. There's no way around it. Regardless of what you attempt to squezze into `buffer[0]`, it will always remain a `char`. In this case the OP is trying to force a pointer value into a `char` object. This is illegal as written, but even if he succeeds to compile it, the end result in `buffer[0]` will be a `char` and certainly not a pointer. It is going to be some unpredictable `char` (`T` in his case), but a `char` neveretheless. Claiming that `buffer[0]` is a pointer in this case is nonsense.

Comment: @AnderyT: first the question stated char *buffer[100], but it was edited later to char buffer[100]. hope that clarifies things.

Comment: @Nik: Oh, OK. Must have been a quick edit, if it is not reflected in the history

Answer (score 7):

`"\n"` is a C string, that is a `char *` pointing at a null terminated series of `char` elements. Your program takes the address of that string, and stores the lowest 8 bits into `buffer[0]`. In your case they happen to be the ASCII code for `T`.

Try the following:

```
char buffer[100];
buffer[0] = '\n';
```

`'\n'` is a `char` literal, so this will behave as expected.

Comment: @Erandros: This is the best answer you received so far. The only side note I'd make is that the behavior described in this answer is allowed to slip through by overly loose error checking in your compiler (happens pretty often in C compiler world), although you should have been paying attention to warnings. A pedantic ANSI C compiler would reject your program outright with an error message.

Comment: I have no idea why this response wasn't chosen as the best answer, or @sees response, as both of you have provided the buffer[0]= '\n'; suggestion, which was the key. Anyway, I saw some of your other questions on SO. They are very interesting in general. Edge cases, or like physical mechanics "thought experiments". So you aren't so clueless, I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: I got it wrong. Your code should be rewritten to the following code:

`char buffer[100]={0};

 buffer[0]= '\n';`